# Removing item's from a Hashset

Tags: java

I'm creating a quiz game. some answers have alternative answers for example:

who's the president of Russia?

> - Vladimir Poetin
> - Poetin

here is the code:

```
for (HashSet<String> answer : answers) {
    for (String alternative : answer) {
        // Apply levensthein
        int distance = levensthein(givenAnswer, alternative);
        double ratio = ((double) distance) / (Math.max(alternative.length(), givenAnswer.length()));
        // 20 % error margin
        if (ratio <= 0.2) {
            // remove this set of answers, so you can't try in the same answer again
            answers.remove(answer);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

After the levensthein check the answer must be removed from the `Hashset`.
it works for when a question doesn't have alternative anwsers.

how can I get this working? any ideas what I do wrong?

thnx!

Comment: use collection's 'iterator()' method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The enhanced for loop is not suitable for removing elements from the Collections you are iterating over. Use an explicit iterator instead.

```
Iterator<HashSet<String>> aIter = answers.iterator();
while (aIter.hasNext()) {
    HashSet<String> answer = aIter.next();
    Iterator<String> iter = answer.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String alternative = iter.next();
        // Apply levensthein
        int distance = levensthein(givenAnswer, alternative);
        double ratio = ((double) distance) / (Math.max(alternative.length(), givenAnswer.length()));
        // 20 % error margin
        if (ratio <= 0.2) {
            // remove this set of answers, so you can't try in the same answer again
            aIter.remove();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! in a couple of minutes I can mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You *should not* use a for loop to go over elements and remove them, this can cause exceptions (if I am not mistaken, `ConcurrentModificationException`).

The `HashSet` provides an explicit [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#iterator--) through which you can remove the elements.

`for (HashSet<HashSet<String>> answer : answers) {` would need to become:

```
Iterator<String answerIter = answers.iterator();
while(answerIter.hasNext()) {
    HashSet<string> answer = answerIter.next();
    ...
    if (ratio <= 0.2) {
        answerIter.remove();
        return true; 
    }
```